# How to dynamically add code in cs files?

Tags: c#, xaml

I'm making a short file to ease my effort writing a javascript through a small WPF application. I have a requirement where I need to create code based on some available classes in the DLL I took reference from.
Problem is I'm not sure I would get particular class every time or not and based on that class I have to make my code.
So If I code considering all the class present and if DLL doesn't have them, it would throw a compilation error. Is there any solution?

Let me clarify by an example.
Referenced DLL can contain three class at max: Vegetables, Fruits and Grains.

My XAML.CS file would be like this

```
main()
{
    method1();
    method2();
    method3();
}

method1()
{
    Vegetables obj = new Vegetables()
    //Code here    
}

method2()
{
    Fruits obj = new Fruits()
    //Code here    
}

method3()
{
    Grains obj = new Grains()
    //Code here    
}
```

There can be one or two class missing from DLL. and my code would throw errors such reference not exist. What can I do in such case?

Comment: Why don't you load the dll at runtime and create the instance of those objects which matches with the defined agreement (either via Interfaces or Attributes)? This can be a quick reference `https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/introduction-to-building-a-plug-in-architecture-using-C-Sharp/`. In that case, you will not end up having exception for not loaded dlls. Your program will work on those dlls which are loaded in AppDomain.

Comment: im not following could you improve the question. not understanding what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @Seabizkit I tried to make it as simple as I can in above example.

Comment: do you not have access to the dll which have the code needed? cant you just load them all at start up...?

Comment: Exactly I don't have any access to mechanism that creates DLL. What I know is there can be such classes in it. If they do, I need to programme accordingly. If they don't I don't need to do so.

Comment: So, um, are you asking how to read the publicly exposed types from a DLL without loading it? Then you need to look into dll file type specs / disassembly techniques...

Comment: @MaulikModi - where would be these classes? In the same assembly or these DLLs are given by other devs or third party?

Comment: @user1672994 By Others

Comment: Then loading via reflection is the best option for your program. Still of taking a reference in your project, you can load the assemblies using `Assembly.Load` or `Assembly.LoadFrom` method.